# MySql foreign key constraint issue

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I am trying to develop a university database and am stuck with few tables throwing a constraint error. I have tried various workarounds:
1. Checking my eninge status. It's INNODB across all tables. 
2. On Update On Delete parameters(although I am not sure if I am doing that correctly).
3. Checking the NULL reference and the data types. Foreign keys referred to have the same data types as the primary key in the table which is making the reference. 
    This is my query:

```
CREATE TABLE Faculty (
FacNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
FacFirstName  VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
 FacLastName   VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
FacCity       VARCHAR(30)   NOT NULL,
FacState      CHAR(2)       NOT NULL,
FacDept       CHAR(6)       NULL,
FacRank       CHAR(4)       NULL,
FacSalary     DECIMAL(10,2) NULL,
FacSupervisor CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
FacHireDate   DATETIME      NULL,
FacZipCode    CHAR(10)      NOT NULL,
CONSTRAINT FacultyPK PRIMARY KEY (FacNo),
CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty
ON DELETE NO ACTION 
ON UPDATE NO ACTION )engine = innodb;
```

This is the OFFERING table making the reference:

```
CREATE TABLE Offering (
OfferNo       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
CourseNo      CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
OffTerm       CHAR(6)       NOT NULL,
OffYear       INTEGER       NOT NULL,
OffLocation   VARCHAR(30)   NULL,
OffTime       VARCHAR(10)   NULL,
FacNo         CHAR(11)      NOT NULL,
OffDays       CHAR(4)       NULL,
CONSTRAINT OfferingPK PRIMARY KEY (OfferNo),
CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course,
CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty  )ENGINE =     INNODB;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your foreign key references are lacking columns:

```
CONSTRAINT SupervisorFK FOREIGN KEY (FacSupervisor) REFERENCES Faculty(Facno)

CONSTRAINT CourseFK FOREIGN KEY (CourseNo) REFERENCES Course(CourseNo),

CONSTRAINT FacultyFK FOREIGN KEY (FacNo) REFERENCES Faculty(FacNo)
```

[Here](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e185e1) is a SQL Fiddle.  It doesn't have the `CourseNo` foreign key, because that isn't defined in the question.